Problems that cannot be integrated during the p4 integ process
enter image description here
Branch A and branch B own file C, then delete C on branch A and then integ to branch B, then C on B is also deleted, then, branch A re-adds file C, then integ to branch B again but The C file of branch B still does not exist and is still deleted.
Branch A and branch B own file C, then delete C on branch A and then integ to branch B, then C on B is also deleted, then, branch A re-adds file C, then integ to branch B again but The C file of branch B still does not exist and is still deleted.
Why?
How to solve？

Let's take it step by step:

Branch A and branch B own file C,

C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 files ...
//stream/main/rb/A/C#1 - add change 515 (text)
//stream/main/rb/B/C#1 - branch change 516 (text)


then delete C on branch A and then integ to branch B,

C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 delete A/...
//stream/main/rb/A/C#1 - opened for delete

C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 submit -d "delete"
Submitting change 517.
Locking 1 files ...
delete //stream/main/rb/A/C#2
Change 517 submitted.

C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 integ A/... B/...
//stream/main/rb/B/C#1 - delete from //stream/main/rb/A/C#2

C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 submit -d "integ delete"
Submitting change 518.
Locking 1 files ...
delete //stream/main/rb/B/C#2
Change 518 submitted.


then C on B is also deleted,

C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 files ...
//stream/main/rb/A/C#2 - delete change 517 (text)
//stream/main/rb/B/C#2 - delete change 518 (text)


then, branch A re-adds file C,

C:\Perforce\test\rb>echo asdfasdfasdfasdf > A/C

C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 add A/...
//stream/main/rb/A/C#2 - opened for add

C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 submit -d readd
Submitting change 519.
Locking 1 files ...
add //stream/main/rb/A/C#3
Change 519 submitted.


then integ to branch B again but The C file of branch B still does not exist and is still deleted.

Hm, nope:
C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 integ -n A/... B/...
//stream/main/rb/B/C#2 - branch/sync from //stream/main/rb/A/C#3

What I think you did at this step was use the p4 merge command:
C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 merge A/... B/...
//stream/main/rb/B/C#2 - sync/delete from //stream/main/rb/A/C#3
... must resolve branch from //stream/main/rb/A/C#3

When you resolve, you have two options:
C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 resolve
c:\Perforce\test\rb\B\C - resolving branch from //stream/main/rb/A/C#3
Branch resolve:
at: branch
ay: ignore
Accept(a) Skip(s) Help(?) at:

If you choose at (the default option), then the file is opened for branch:
Accept(a) Skip(s) Help(?) at: at
//Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/rb/B/C - branch from //stream/main/rb/A/C

But according to your Revision Graph screenshot, you chose ay to ignore the branch:
Accept(a) Skip(s) Help(?) at: ay
//Samwise-dvcs-1509687817/rb/B/C - ignored //stream/main/rb/A/C

which leaves the file as a delete to record that you chose not to branch it (but want to record the branch as having been ignored, which requires a new revision):
C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 opened
//stream/main/rb/B/C#2 - delete default change (text)

C:\Perforce\test\rb>p4 resolved
c:\Perforce\test\rb\B\C - ignored //stream/main/rb/A/C#3
c:\Perforce\test\rb\B\C - resolved branch from //stream/main/rb/A/C#3

If you want to branch the file, then when resolve asks "branch or ignore" you need to pick branch, not ignore.
Note that since at is the default resolve option in this scenario, doing resolve -as will also result in opening the file for branch, and the default behavior of p4 integ (not p4 merge) is to automatically branch the file in this situation without even scheduling a resolve.  The only way you end up with an ignore is by explicitly choosing it.

this location：”What I think you did at this step was use the p4 merge command“
I use the integ command。
The core commands called by the script are:

I also agree with your explanation of the -af and -at parameters, but I still need to think about the specific logic.
this step：What I think you did at this step was use the p4 merge command:  Just run the p4 integ command
command:
p4 -p p4.master.com:1666 -u build -c ci.local.com--TargetBranch integ -c 354643 -Af  -S //GameProject/Project_OB6 -r -P //GameProject/Project_trunk "..."

You can have a branch resolve scheduled by a p4 integ if there's a conflict where some revisions of A that you're trying to branch are credited into B and others aren't.  But again, you'll be given the at/ay choice.  Does your script always run p4 resolve -ay on a conflict (ignoring the parent stream)?

https://portal.perforce.com/s/article/15222

My problem is more likely caused by this

Yes, the example I gave you that matches your rev graph is functionally identical to the one in that KB article.
In any case, the main thing is to not use ay when you don't want to ignore the source of the integrate.
